# C# Convert from .NET 3.5 to 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I had to downgrade my program from  .NET 3.5 to 3.0. What I did was go `properties->application` and change the "Target Framework" from 3.5 to 3.0. is this the correct step? now I get warnings:

I only have this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
```

but yet I get this

> Warning   1   The primary reference "System.Core", which is a framework
>   assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework.
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v3.0". To resolve this problem, either remove
>   the reference "System.Core" or retarget your application to a
>   framework version which contains "System.Core".   ProgName1
>
> Warning   2   The primary reference "System.Xml.Linq" could not be
>   resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework
>   assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.0". To resolve
>   this problem, either remove the reference "System.Xml.Linq" or
>   retarget your application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". ProgName1
>
> Warning   3   The primary reference "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" could
>   not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework
>   assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the
>   currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.0". To resolve
>   this problem, either remove the reference
>   "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" or retarget your application to a
>   framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".    ProgName1
>
> Warning   4   The primary reference "System.Xml.Linq", which is a
>   framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted
>   framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.0". To resolve this problem,
>   either remove the reference "System.Xml.Linq" or retarget your
>   application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Xml.Linq".    ProgName1
>
> Warning   5   The primary reference "System.Data.DataSetExtensions", which
>   is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently
>   targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.0". To resolve this
>   problem, either remove the reference "System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
>   or retarget your application to a framework version which contains
>   "System.Data.DataSetExtensions".  ProgName1

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove those references in your project and reload the appropriate references with `Add Reference` from the dialog box.

Answer (score 5):

The warnings are telling you that those five assemblies are new to .Net 3.5 and cannot be referenced from .Net 3.0.
Just delete those references.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Extension methods extensivly and this is one of the main reasons you're getting most of these errors.

You need 3.5 for extension methods.